# Vertical Navbar for desktop collapsing to full-width horizontal navbar for mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

like the title says I need my 100% vertical height navbar to collapse into a full-width horizontal navbar for smaller screens (when the screen becomes ~580px in width).

[Here is a jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/s92h3bLu/) of what I have currently.

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul {
  height: 100% width: 10%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
  color: #2A2829;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  background-color: pink;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: pink;
}

.body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  float: right;
  color: pink;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">BUSINESS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">SCHOOL</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    
    <p>
    Adding space <br />
    to make <br />
    navbar longer <br />
    </p>
  </ul>

  <div class="body">
    <div>
      <h1>
      Hello World
      </h1>
      <p>
        blah blah blah blah blah blah
      </p>
      <p>
        blah blah blah blah blah blah
      </p>
      <p>
        blah blah blah blah blah blah
      </p>
      <p>
        blah blah blah blah blah blah
      </p>
      <p>
        blah blah blah blah blah blah
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

From there, I want something like the below if the screen size is smaller:

[image: something like this]

I found two really good resources that I think should be able to help me, but I am having trouble implementing the system with my webpage.

Also, I am not using Bootstrap at the moment, would it be easier to complete this project if I do use Bootstrap? I'm still very new to web development so I apologize in advance for any of my newbiness!

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea here is that you start with mobile first styles and work upward.

Then make small changes to your css styles as the viewport exceeds a certain width (580px in this case).

```css
html {
  height: 100%
}
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%
}
ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: #2A2829;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: pink;
}
@media (min-width: 580px) {
  ul {
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul li a:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: pink;
}
.body {
  color: pink;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
}
@media (min-width: 580px) {
  .body {
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    width: 90%;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">BUSINESS</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">SCHOOL</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a>
    </li>

    <p>
      Adding space
      <br />to make
      <br />navbar longer
      <br />
    </p>
  </ul>
  <div class="body">
    <div>
      <h1>
      Hello World
      </h1>
      <p>
        blah blah blah blah blah blah
      </p>
      <p>
        blah blah blah blah blah blah
      </p>
      <p>
        blah blah blah blah blah blah
      </p>
      <p>
        blah blah blah blah blah blah
      </p>
      <p>
        blah blah blah blah blah blah
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e55xm437/1/

Comment: I like this approach, I tried it and it worked beautifully. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a CSS media query for screens smaller than 580 px in width. For example, to make your navigation list cover the entire screen when on a mobile device:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
  ul {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```